# Do annotations in Java result in compile-time transitive dependencies?

Tags: java, annotations, persistence, javac

A simple example where `Ent.java` uses annotations and is compiled with the necessary jar dependency after which `Includer.java` is compiled which in turn imports `Ent.java`.

**Ent.java:**

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="securities")
public class Ent {}
```

**Includer.java:**

```
public class Includer {

    public void f() {
        Ent s = new Ent();
    }
}
```

Compiling this with...

```
javac -cp C:/apache-tomcat-7.0.59/lib/javax.persistence_2.1.0.v201304241213.jar Ent.java
javac Includer.java
```

...results in the following warning when compiling `Includer.java`:

```
.\Ent.class: warning: Cannot find annotation method 'name()' in type 'Table': class file for javax.persistence.Table not found
```

The same happens of course if we add more annotations but only annotations that take parameters seem to be causing this behaviour. Adding the jar dependency from the first compilation to the classpath when compiling `Includer.java` solves the problem but doesn't follow how I usually think dependencies are handled. Since I'm quite new to annotations, is it the expected behaviour that we need to add the dependencies of `Ent.java` to the classpath when compiling `Includer.java` (adding dependencies of dependencies so to speak...) or is this likely some sort of bug or some other kind of special case...? Compiler version javac 1.8.0_31 was used for this test.

Answer (score 2):

This seems related to [this bug: JDK-6550655](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6550655):

> Compiler error when compiling a class alone that depends on another class, which has already been compiled and has a dependency on a class from persistence-api.jar

Also see related bug [JDK-6365854: javac crashes when compiling against an annotated class](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6365854).

To answer your question, it is not required to place dependencies of the dependency class (`Ent.java`) to the classpath of the depending class (`Includer.java`). However, it seems `javac` also reads the annotations in the dependency class. According to the referenced bug, this used to cause a compilation failure (a `com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure`). As mentioned in the comments, this is modified to only throw a warning:

> After the fix, the compiler will accept the program but issue
> a warning.  The rationale is that the missing annotation can cause
> problems when running the program.

Also from the comments:

> The compiler should not crash and this problem will be addressed first.
>
> While it is desireable to allow the compilation to continue without the
> annotation, I will have to investigate if it is allowable.  For example,
> the compiler cannot determine if the missing annotation has the
> meta-annotation @Inherited.
> This can cause problems for annotation processors.

Comment: None of your links work for me. Also, just to be super clear, you say that the expected behaviour is that we don't need to add dependencies of dependencies, then you say that javac must see the annotations, so what does this last remark amount to? We still don't have to treat annotations differently from how we treat class dependencies, right? Also, it would be interesting to know why they don't solve this permanently in the persistence library(ies)...

Comment: ...is it the same with all providers or specifically Eclipselink? Because it is indeed a bug then (actually two bugs; first of all that the compiler crashes (fixed) and second of all, that we need to act this way in this particular case (w persistence library(ies?)).

Comment: @fast-reflexes The second link (I'm also not able to open them now but yesterday they worked...) indicates it's not just related to this persistence library. You still don't need to add transitive dependencies as I mentioned, so my point was that you can ignore the compiler warning.

Comment: @fast-reflexes I found these two links which point to the same bugs: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6365854 and https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6550655.

Comment: Thanks again! I wanna mark this as the accepted answer but I don't quite understand still... One of the bug reports mostly relates to that the compiler crashes and the fact that it, later after having fixed the crash, issues a warning seems to be the desired behaviour... so does this mean that this is the behaviour for all annotation classes (even though we can ignore it) or is this a bug in the 
persistence jars?

Comment: I guess my lack of understanding might relate to how annotations work maybe (retention policies?) but to me it seems like
all the info in Ent should be in place after it's been compiled and therefore the problems when compiling Includer seems totally wrong (even though they might be ignored)... and if it's NOT a bug in the persistence jars, then I'm back to square one :)
also, if it's a bug in persistence jars, why don't they fix it?

Comment: @fast-reflexes https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6365854 indicates it's not just for the persistence jar. I do agree the warning does not make sense and yes, all the info are there in `Ent.class`, however not all the info of its annotation (namely the `Table` type in this case) is present on the compiler classpath, hence the warning message. The info of this annotation is needed for the reasons mentioned in the bug reports: "While it is desireable to allow the compilation to continue without the annotation, ... This can cause problems for annotation processors."